# Mis archivos descargados utilizando selenium en lambda no se descargan en el directorio "/tmp"

Tags: selenium, aws, selenium-webdriver, lambda

No puedo cambiar la ubicación de descarga predeterminada de Chrome en AWS lambda a /tmp.

Estoy automatizando un sitio web usando selenium que básicamente descarga un archivo .xls del sitio web a la "ubicación deseada" cuando se ejecuta localmente en Mac o Windows, pero no sé dónde se descarga en el modo sin cabeza de AWS Lambda.

Quiero almacenar/descargar el archivo en la ubicación /tmp mientras hago clic en el botón de descarga durante la automatización

El siguiente código funciona en local, pero en AWS Lambda no funciona, ya que el archivo no está almacenado al hacer click " input_descarga_sectores.click()".En lambda no obtengo ningún tipo de error

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import boto3
import os
import tempfile

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

bucketname = 'archivos-excel-rh'

def main(event, context):

    #definir opciones de chrome
    options = Options()

    options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')  # Deshabilitar el bloqueo de ventanas emergentes
    options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection') 
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--no-first-run')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--disable-client-side-phishing-detection')
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
    
    prefs = {"browser.downloads.dir": "//tmp//", "download.default_directory": "//tmp//", "directory_upgrade": True}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
    
    
    # Despues redirigir a otra pagina de la intranet
    driver.get('https://cl.controlroll.com/rh01/cecos.aspx?p=1LCGYZAD602F0XA2DW00')
    
    input_descarga_sectores = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ctl00$espacio_body$ctl03')
    input_descarga_sectores.click()

    #esperar 5 segundos para que se descargue el archivo
    time.sleep(15)

    #print carpeta temporal
    print(os.listdir('/tmp'))
    
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "hola mundo"
        
    }

    return response
```